# error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

when i want to update or install any package i got this error:

for example : whealln i exec this sudo apt upgrade or sudo apt install zsh

```
 dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (--remove):
     installed linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Try posting this on the [Linux specific Stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

These commands should hopefully work. They will do a full clean and reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove   
sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean   
sudo apt-get -f install    
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a   
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```